# python - performance - sqlite3 or large lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, sqlite

I have a local database with many SQL tables (~20m rows per table) that I need to iterate through.  Each row has an epoch date value, but these are not unique.  For example, there might be 10 rows with the same date followed by a gap of 100 seconds or more.  Another program sends a query saying "i want to see information for this range of dates".  I need to fetch the requested rows, format them into a list of dictionaries, and return this to the program that requested it.  The requests are typically only for a period of 1-2 seconds but occasionally they may be as long as a day.  The requests always move forward in time, never backward, but the same date is often requested more than once.  The faster I can return the data, the sooner the other program can make its next request, and the sooner we can both go home :)

What do you think would be the quickest way to handle this situation?

A - frequent queries to the database for rows meeting my date requirements each second, format the the query results, return them.

B - periodic queries loading many rows at once into a list of dictionaries ordered by date. lots of next() and index() as the list is sliced and returned to the other program. once the list shrinks beyond a defined length another DB query is made to regrow it.

C - the same periodic queries for many rows, but place the results into an sqlite database.  then make frequent smaller queries to this in-memory database, format the results, return them.

I feel B and C should definitely be quicker than A.  But will I see better performance working with a smaller in-memory DB, or slicing away from the beginning of a long list of dictionaries?  Or maybe there is another option I have not considered?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Sound like a very simple case for a database. There might be potential to optimize. Make sure you have proper indexes and if possible merge all data into one table.

Comment: _but the same date is often requested more than once_ sounds like a job for the [memcached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) daemon and `python-memcached`.

Comment: Why do you think that the database (and its own cache) are too slow for you? Have you any measurements?